# Forcing the use of aliased controllers

Tags: routes, controller, cakephp-1.3, alias

I have a controller, named: `SomeLongUnfriendlyName`
In the router I gave it an alias: `CoolName`
Now, whenever someone calls `/CoolName/theAction`, the `/SomeLongUnfriendlyName/theAction` is executed. so far so good.
My problem is that I want to deny the use of the original `SomeLongUnfriendlyName` name.

How can it be done?

---

pop pop pop

Comment: I guess you could route it somewhere else that would give a 404, but that seems silly. Or, implement a custom route class that will redirect if it detects the original controller name. Either way, it seems a bit silly. I'm curious as to the reason behind this?

Comment: SEO, I have Several controllers that do similar jobs but I need them to output the data under the same alias

Comment: You could use htaccess file to prevent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add it as a redirect route (if you're using Cake 2.x). I've never tried anything but from what I know about the routing system, if you place this last and none of the other routes catch, it will do a proper redirect to the aliased controller.

```
Router::redirect(
  '/SomeLongUnfriendlyName/*', 
  array('controller' => 'CoolName'), 
  array('status' => 302)
);
```

Here we're redirecting the name you don't want to use to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the beforeFilter method of your App controller to check whether the given URI has a corresponding route. If it does, just issue a redirect to the routed class.
Make sure you check the URL shown on the browser to avoid an infinite redirection.